# Why does defining this size variable as const result in memory being zeroed out? (godbolt example included)

Tags: c++, variable-length-array

Compiler Explorer Example: https://godbolt.org/z/AEv4Ci

This code

```
int main() {
  const int Size = 16; <-- const
  int arr1[Size];
  int arr2[Size];
  int arr3[Size];
  for (auto I = 0; I < Size; ++I) {
    arr3[I] = arr1[I] + arr2[I];
  }
  return arr3[Size - 1];
}
```

returns `0`

but this code:

```
int main() {
  int Size = 16; // <-- not const
  int arr1[Size];
  int arr2[Size];
  int arr3[Size];
  for (auto I = 0; I < Size; ++I) {
    arr3[I] = arr1[I] + arr2[I];
  }
  return arr3[Size - 1];
}
```

returns a random number

Comment: Please only tag the language you are compiling it against. You should do that in general and in this particular case C and C++ are indeed different: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1887097/why-arent-variable-length-arrays-part-of-the-c-standard

Comment: Choose language, VLA is allowed in C, not in C++.

Comment: But reading uninitialized variables is UB for both of your snippets.

Comment: Both versions are Undefined Behaviour, and the fact that one has different output than output is completely random.

Comment: I'm removing the C tag and leaving C++ since your godbolt example is in C++. If this is in fact a question about C, feel free to edit it the other way.

Comment: `arr3[I] = arr1[I] + arr2[I];` is adding uninitialised variables. That's [undefined behaviour](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub) and *any* result is acceptable.

Comment: three comments above are correct answers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> int Size = 16; // <-- not const
> int arr1[Size];
> ```

This program is ill-formed in C++, because non-compile-time-constant values may not be used as the size of an array.

> ```
> arr3[I] = arr1[I] + arr2[I];
> ```

The values of `arr1[I]` and `arr2[I]` are indeterminate. The behaviour of reading an indeterminate value is undefined.

> Why does ... result in ...? ... but this code ... returns a random number

Because in both cases, behaviour of the program is undefined.

Answer (score 0):

In both case you essentially reading an unitialized data so the program returns garbage values. It just an accident that it returns 0. Try with `Size = 14` for example or other number it will also return some random values in the `const` case too.

Answer (score 0):

The 2nd code

```
int Size = 16; // <-- not const
int arr1[Size];
```

is in error in VS C++ (some compilers allow it).

In the code arr1, arr2 are not initialized, arr1[I], arr2[I] , arr3[I] have indeterminate values, assignment “arr3[I] = arr1[I] + arr2[I];” has undefined behavior.

Undefined behavior manifests itself as taking arbitrary values currently stored in arr1[I], arr2[I] and saving result of the “+” in arr3[I]. Concrete values in arr1[I], arr2[I] could change between runs or during the same run.